# Meteor method won't update using call/methods

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I can't get a document to update when using the following code:

client.js

```
// Update the story
Meteor.call('storyEdit', FlowRouter.getParam("_id"), story, function(result){

  // put stuff here

});
```

server.js

```
Meteor.methods({
  'storyEdit': function( id, doc ){

    // console.log(doc);

    // Update the user
    Stories.update(id,{$set:doc},function(error){
      if (error) {
          throw new Meteor.Error(500, error.message);
      } else {
          console.log("Update Successful");
      }
    // response
    });

  // settings
  }
});
```

The document has a lot of nested element in it. Four under the top most node. So like:

```
{  
   title:'.',
   genre:'...',
   author:'...',
   description:'...',
   image:'...',
   audio:{  
      intro:'',
      background:'...',
      outro:'...'
   },
   credits:[  
      {  
         'Story by ':'...'
      },
      {  
         'Music by ':'...'
      },
      {  
         'Illustrations by ':'...'
      }
   ],
   chapters:[  
      {  
         title:'Chapter One',
         pages:'[Object]',
         audio:{  

         }
      },
      {  
         title:'Chapter Two',
         pages:'[Object]',
         audio:{  

         }
      },
      {  
         title:'Chapter Three',
         pages:'[Object]',
         audio:{  

         }
      },
      {  
         title:'Chapter Four',
         pages:'[Object]',
         audio:{  

         }
      },
      {  
         title:'Chapter Five',
         pages:'[Object]',
         audio:{  

         }
      },
      {  
         title:'Chapter Six',
         pages:'[Object]',
         audio:{  

         }
      }
   ],
   published:false
}
```

*The above I've manually serialized, so there might be mistakes*

And from the terminal they're being output as `[object]`, but I just figured that was expected behaviour to save room on the terminal. Could this be the problem? I would expect I can just update endless child nodes (to a point).

Log outputs that the update was successful. Nothing ever changes. The terminal looks fine too.

Any thoughts?

***EDIT***

Working this probably backwards, I can't get this update to update even the most basic things, like the title. Here's an example:

```
export const Stories = new Mongo.Collection('stories');

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  // This code only runs on the server
  Meteor.publish('stories', function(){
    return Stories.find();
  });

}

Meteor.methods({
  'storyEdit': function( id, doc ){

    // Update the document
    Stories.update({id:'58772299f8a253cabcbc625a'},{$set:{title:"123"}},function(error,result){
      console.log(error,result);
      if (error) {
          throw new Meteor.Error(500, error.message);
      } else {
          console.log("Update Successful");
      }
    // response
    });

  // storyEdit
  }
});
```

And then from the terminal, just doing a simple find to see if anything has been updated:

`db.stories.find({"_id" : ObjectId("58772299f8a253cabcbc625a")},{title:1});`

The title, never, ever changes. What am I missing here? Could it be permissions during the edit stage? I get 0 as a result. So it's like the two ids are totally different.

Comment: I think your mongo query is incorrect. If you can show the nested mongo object you are updating than probably can give you some ideas

Comment: I edited nearly at the same time. :)

Comment: Do you want to update the complete chapter object?

Comment: The entire object has been serialized on the client beforehand, so effectively I just want to overwrite the document entirely and only retain the _id. I don't want to access fields individually.

Comment: A string and an objectId are not the same thing. In addition, in order to properly return a value to the method user, you should use synchronous syntax (i.e, don't use a callback on the server). If you created the document using Mongo and did not change Meteor's default id type to objectId, then this is likely where your problem is. Change the document's id to a string and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you update the mongo document using set:

```
    Stories.update({_id:'your id'},{$set:{'chapter':yourDoc}},function(error,result){
        if(error){
            throw new Meteor.Error(500, error.message);
        }
        else {
            console.log('success')
        }
   })
```

checkout some difference between set addToSet and push, it might help.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is updated because you are using the wrong `_id` value, I see that you are using this `_id` to match the document: `58772299f8a253cabcbc625a` in your code, but in terminal you are using another value `ObjectId("58772299f8a253cabcbc625a")`. These are two different values, that is the reason why you could not update your document.

To convert a string to a Mongo ObjectId, you could use this function:

```
const _id = new Mongo.ObjectID('58772299f8a253cabcbc625a');
```

Answer (score 0):

You did almost everything just right, if you store ids as `ObjectId` you need to look for `_id` and not `id`. this should fix your problem

```
export const Stories = new Mongo.Collection('stories');

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  // This code only runs on the server
  Meteor.publish('stories', function(){
    return Stories.find();
  });
}

Meteor.methods({
  'storyEdit': function( id, doc ){
    const _id = new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID('58772299f8a253cabcbc625a')
    // Update the document
    Stories.update({ _id }, { $set: { title: '123' } }, function (error,result) {
      console.log(error, result);
      if (error) {
        throw new Meteor.Error(500, error.message);
      } else {
        console.log("Update Successful");
      }
    // response
    });
  // storyEdit
  }
});
```